# Higher cost running Antminer S9 w/ APW3++ when running at 220v?

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer, psu

There's plenty of discussions on 110v vs 220v on the web and I'm successfully running 2 Antminer s9's on a 30amp circuit at 110v (or maybe it's 120/125, I don't know how that works).

I have not hooked up a volt/watt meter tool up, but if the APW3++ is to deliver 1200 watts @ 110v or 1600 watts @ 220v, does that mean it will cost me more KwH's to run on 220v, therefore making it less profitable?

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [AntMiner S9i 13.5 TH/sec model](http://shop.bitmain.com/product/detail?pid=000201805232004050031SSFbtc00669) requires 101.5 Amps DC.  Since power (watts) is equal to voltage multiplied by amps, the total power consumed by the AntMiner is 1218 watts (+/- 10%).  Note, this is regardless of whether that's AC or DC, and regardless of voltage.  1218 watts is 1218 watts, or if you run it for an hour, 1.218 KW/hr.  In my case, that works out to about $54.44 USD per month, regardless of voltage.

The [APW3++](http://shop.bitmain.com/product/detail?pid=00020180322153931277t0oJTIUc06AA) *power supply* doesn't care what A/C voltage you supply it with, in the range of 100 to 240 volts, it simply converts that into the required amps output in DC.  If the AntMiner is puling 1218 watts, that will translate (at 93% efficiency) to 11.85 amps at 110 volts, or 5.43 amps at 240 volts.  Running two AntMiner S9s on a single 120 volt 15 amp circuit is pushing the boundaries of [safe operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Tables_of_AWG_wire_sizes).  You should ensure you only run a single AntMiner per 110 volt circuit, unless those circuits are fed with 12 gauge or lower wiring, and are rated for at least 20 amps.

Attaching the APW3++ power supplies to 240 volt circuits simply means you are pulling less amps per hour than if it is connected to a 120 volt circuit, and you can connect two, or possibly three, AntMiners to a single 240 volt circuit.

So, to answer your question, no, it's not more expensive to run at 240 volts than 120 volts.  In fact, due to [power efficiency](https://www.sunpower-uk.com/glossary/what-is-power-supply-efficiency/), it's probably very slightly cheaper to run at 240 volts.

Comment: So i believe the wiring is only 14 gauge and the circuit breakers are 30amps. How do i know what gauge of wire I can use? If i change to 240v so that I can run more Antminer's on a single 30 amp breaker, what is the most number of Antminers I can run and what gauage of wire will I need?

Comment: You really should engage a local electrician to ensure you meet local code requirements.  If your house burns down because of incorrectly installed circuits, you could be completely liable.

Comment: If you try to run an s9 in your house you probably won't be able to sleep

Comment: @Learn2Mine - that depends on a lot of factors such as proximity of your head to the AntMiner, whether you have noise mitigation in place, etc, etc.  Also, some people *like* noise when they sleep.

Comment: Feeding 14 gauge wire on a 30amp breaker is likely a violation of your local electrical code. Depending on which spec you need to meet 30amp needs 10 or 12 gauge.

Answer (score 0):

it is the same 110 vs 220 in household electrical it has nothing to due with the supplied voltage. a house service comes off the transformer with two legs of 240 or 220
then in the rails it is broken down into two seperate legs of 120
240 household circuit is two 120 combined normally you go on one rail of the 240 service.
the transformer does not care...so to say 240 or 120 saves you money is moot...the meter does not care.

Comment: It's generally the case that computer powersupplies are a couple percent more efficient on 240v than they are on 120v.  Running lower currents also results is less resistive losses in cabling (though if this latter effect isn't small you're overloading your cables).